# the featured products arent displayed in my home page

Tags: magento, magento2

I have a problem when i filtered the products , and i try to print it , it works and i see only the featured products in the array here.

```
        echo '<pre>';
        print_r($_productCollection->getData());
        echo '</pre>';
```

but when the loop for the $_productCollection happens , all products are loading not the featured only why ?? and as i said that when i print the variable i got featured products correctly

```
<?php

use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action;

?>

<section class="container-fluid one">
    <div class="all-products">
        <p class='products-text'>featured products</p>


        <?php
        $_productCollection = $block->getLoadedProductCollection();
        $_productCollection->addAttributeToSelect('*');
        $_productCollection->addAttributeToFilter('featured', ['eq' => 1]);

        $new =$_productCollection->getData();
        
        echo '<pre>';
        print_r($_productCollection->getData());
        echo '</pre>';

        $_helper = $this->helper(Magento\Catalog\Helper\Output::class);
        ?>
        <?php if (!$_productCollection->count()) : ?>
        <div class="message info empty">
            <div><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('We can\'t find products matching the selection.')) ?></div>
        </div>
        <?php else : ?>
        <?= $block->getToolbarHtml() ?>
        <?= $block->getAdditionalHtml() ?>
        <?php
            if ($block->getMode() == 'grid') {
                $viewMode = 'grid';
                $image = 'category_page_grid';
                $showDescription = false;
                $templateType = \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ReviewRendererInterface::SHORT_VIEW;
            } else {
                $viewMode = 'list';
                $image = 'category_page_list';
                $showDescription = true;
                $templateType = \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ReviewRendererInterface::FULL_VIEW;
            }
            /**
             * Position for actions regarding image size changing in vde if needed
             */
            $pos = $block->getPositioned();
            ?>
        <div class="container<?= /* @noEscape */ $viewMode ?> products-<?= /* @noEscape */ $viewMode ?>">
            <?php $iterator = 1; ?>
            <div class="swiper mySwiper">
                <ol class="swiper-wrapper">
                    <?php /** @var $_product \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product */ ?>
                    <?php foreach ($_productCollection as $_product) : ?>



                    <?= /* @noEscape */ ($iterator++ == 1) ? '<li class="item product product-item swiper-slide">' : '</li><li class="item product product-item swiper-slide">' ?>
                    <a class='product-wishlist' href="<?php echo $this->getUrl('wishlist') ?>">
                        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="20" height="20" fill="black" class="bi bi-heart"
                            viewBox="0 0 16 16">
                            <path
                                d="m8 2.748-.717-.737C5.6.281 2.514.878 1.4 3.053c-.523 1.023-.641 2.5.314 4.385.92 1.815 2.834 3.989 6.286 6.357 3.452-2.368 5.365-4.542 6.286-6.357.955-1.886.838-3.362.314-4.385C13.486.878 10.4.28 8.717 2.01L8 2.748zM8 15C-7.333 4.868 3.279-3.04 7.824 1.143c.06.055.119.112.176.171a3.12 3.12 0 0 1 .176-.17C12.72-3.042 23.333 4.867 8 15z" />
                        </svg>
                    </a>
                    <div data-container="product-<?= /* @noEscape */ $viewMode ?>">
                        <?php
                                $productImage = $block->getImage($_product, $image);
                                if ($pos != null) {
                                    $position = ' style="left:' . $productImage->getWidth() . 'px;'
                                        . 'top:' . $productImage->getHeight() . 'px;"';
                                }
                                ?>
                        <?php // Product Image 
                                ?>
                        <a href="<?= $block->escapeUrl($_product->getProductUrl()) ?>" tabindex="-1">
                            <?= $productImage->toHtml() ?>
                        </a>
                        <div class="holder">
                            <?php
                                    $_productNameStripped = $block->stripTags($_product->getName(), null, true);
                                    ?>
                            <strong>
                                <a href="<?= $block->escapeUrl($_product->getProductUrl()) ?>">
                                    <?php
                                            $productName = $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getName(), 'name');
                                            if (strlen($productName) > 32) {
                                                $productName = substr($productName, 0, 30) . "...";
                                            }
                                            echo $productName;
                                            ?>

                                </a>
                            </strong>
                            <?= $block->getReviewsSummaryHtml($_product, $templateType) ?>
                            <?= /* @noEscape */ $block->getProductPrice($_product) ?>
                            <?= $block->getProductDetailsHtml($_product) ?>

                            <div>
                                <div
                                    <?= strpos($pos, $viewMode . '-actions') ? $block->escapeHtmlAttr($position) : '' ?>>
                                    <div
                                        <?= strpos($pos, $viewMode . '-primary') ? $block->escapeHtmlAttr($position) : '' ?>>
                                        <?php if ($_product->isSaleable()) : ?>
                                        <?php $postParams = $block->getAddToCartPostParams($_product); ?>
                                        <form data-role="tocart-form"
                                            data-product-sku="<?= $block->escapeHtml($_product->getSku()) ?>"
                                            action="<?= $block->escapeUrl($postParams['action']) ?>" method="post">
                                            <input type="hidden" name="product"
                                                value="<?= /* @noEscape */ $postParams['data']['product'] ?>">
                                            <input type="hidden"
                                                name="<?= /* @noEscape */ Action::PARAM_NAME_URL_ENCODED ?>"
                                                value="<?= /* @noEscape */ $postParams['data'][Action::PARAM_NAME_URL_ENCODED] ?>">
                                            <?= $block->getBlockHtml('formkey') ?>
                                            <button type="submit"
                                                title="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr(__('Add to Cart')) ?>"
                                                class="action tocart primary" disabled>
                                                <span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Add to Cart')) ?></span>
                                            </button>
                                        </form>
                                        <?php else : ?>
                                        <?php if ($_product->isAvailable()) : ?>
                                        <div class="stock available">
                                            <span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('In stock')) ?></span>
                                        </div>
                                        <?php else : ?>
                                        <div class="stock unavailable">
                                            <span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Out of stock')) ?></span>
                                        </div>
                                        <?php endif; ?>
                                        <?php endif; ?>
                                    </div>
                                    <div data-role="add-to-links"
                                        <?= strpos($pos, $viewMode . '-secondary') ? $block->escapeHtmlAttr($position) : '' ?>>
                                        <?php if ($addToBlock = $block->getChildBlock('addto')) : ?>
                                        <?= $addToBlock->setProduct($_product)->getChildHtml() ?>
                                        <?php endif; ?>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <?php if ($showDescription) : ?>
                                <div>
                                    <?= /* @noEscape */ $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getShortDescription(), 'short_description') ?>
                                    <a href="<?= $block->escapeUrl($_product->getProductUrl()) ?>"
                                        title="<?= /* @noEscape */ $_productNameStripped ?>"><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Learn More')) ?></a>
                                </div>
                                <?php endif; ?>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <?= ($iterator == count($_productCollection) + 1) ? '</li>' : '' ?>
                    <?php endforeach; ?>
                </ol>

            </div>
        </div>
        <?= $block->getToolbarHtml() ?>
        <?php if (!$block->isRedirectToCartEnabled()) : ?>
        <script type="text/x-magento-init">
            {
            "[data-role=tocart-form], .form.map.checkout": {
                "catalogAddToCart": {
                    "product_sku": "<?= $block->escapeJs($_product->getSku()) ?>"
                }
            }
        }
        </script>
        <?php endif; ?>
        <?php endif; ?>

        <a class="shop" href="zmerly/shop">show all</a>
    </div>

</section>
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason is simple `$_productCollection->getData()` did not call the load method, you can see it here `vendor/magento/framework/Data/Collection/AbstractDb.php`

```
    public function getData()
{
    if ($this->_data === null) {
        $this->_renderFilters()->_renderOrders()->_renderLimit();
        $select = $this->getSelect();
        $this->_data = $this->_fetchAll($select);
        $this->_afterLoadData();
    }
    return $this->_data;
}
```

otherwise, `<?php foreach ($_productCollection as $_product) : ?>` will actually running `load` function, which will build the proper MySQL for getting product

```
    public function getItems()
{
    $this->load();
    return $this->_items;
}
```

Comment: So now what should I do? I used getData function to see the getting results only and I get the correctly the featured items but when the loop happens,it is like looping through all items not filtered items, where is the problem?I tried to loop on a new variable that holds the filtered array from getData() function but it's not working as I expected, my problem isn't with using getData() my problem is how I can loop on (filtered array) only not all items

Comment: Ah, I see, that because you updated the code in `.phtml` file, and collection already loaded before went to `.phtml` file, so it will not work
You need to update the filter in `class` block, for example here `vendor/magento/module-catalog/Block/Product/ListProduct.php` function `initializeProductCollection`, you also can use the event `catalog_block_product_list_collection` to update it, but not in `.phtml` file

besides, the method you're using `getLoadedProductCollection` got a reason for its name

Comment: i simply used clear() before filtration